# Android: How to create a button that produces the same result as hitting the down key on the D-Pad?

Tags: android

How do you create a button in an Android app that produces the same result as hitting the down key on the D-Pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a key event of type [KCODE_DPAD_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN).  To send an event, you can use

```
InputMethodService.sendDownUpKeyEvents(keyEventCode);
```

See [creating input method](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html) for more ways to send key events.

Comment: Thank you for the help... unfortunately i am having a hard time getting it to work... i keep getting the error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method sendDownUpKeyEvents(int) from the type InputMethodService" any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, that's because sendDownUpKeyEvent isn't static, sorry the docs made it look like it was.  I think that method might only apply in an IME, not an activity.  See http://www.anddev.org/throwing-simulating_keystrokes_programatically-t717.html for another way to send key events.